# FLEX 4-> ModuleLoader -> load as bytearray

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

do you know where is the problem with the flex4 ModuleLoader and loadmodule as bytearray?

ml.loadModule("filewithswfcontent.php", null); // ----- WORKS PERFECTLY

ml.loadModule(null, bytearrayloadedbyurlloader); // ---- NOTHING

Here is my mxml file...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="loadIndex();">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.ModuleEvent;

        private function loadIndex():void{
            var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("index.php");
            var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadIndexResult);
            urlloader.load(urlreq);
        }

        private function loadIndexResult(event:Event):void{
            var urlloader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
            urlloader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadIndexResult);
            var barray:ByteArray; 
            barray = (urlloader.data as ByteArray);

            //ml.loadModule("index.php", null); // ----- WORKS PERFECTLY
            ml.loadModule(null, barray); // ---- NOTHING
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:ModuleLoader id="ml" width="500" height="500"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two modifications

1. Specify URLLoader data format
2. Give some string as url in loadModule.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"    minHeight="600" creationComplete="loadIndex();">
   <fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
       import mx.events.ModuleEvent;

       private function loadIndex():void{
           var urlreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("index.php");
           var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
           urlloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
           urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadIndexResult);
           urlloader.load(urlreq);
       }

       private function loadIndexResult(event:Event):void{
           var urlloader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
           urlloader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadIndexResult);
           var barray:ByteArray; 
           barray = (urlloader.data as ByteArray);

           //ml.loadModule("index.php", null); // ----- WORKS PERFECTLY
           ml.loadModule("MyModule", barray); // ---- WORKS PERFECTLY :)
       }
   ]]>
   </fx:Script>
   <s:ModuleLoader id="ml" width="500" height="500"/>
   </s:Application>
   ```